# Dynamic page title based on url

Tags: php, html

Hi lets say my url is www.mywebsite.com/category/music

using php how could I dynamically add a page title of the last part of the url which in this case is music. but as the the url changes how to grab the last part of that url.

At the moment im using

`<?echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>`

But this shows the whole url. how can I remove specific words like "category" and remove forward slashes.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show what code you've tried, else, it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: Use of the `$_SERVER` array and some other PHP functions probably...

Comment: <title><?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?></title>

Comment: i have used the above but this only is showing me /

Comment: Then you need some `if` conditions when what you get is not what you want. If you are on other pages, that will populate with something, but not on the home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<title><?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?></title>
```

Or

```
 <title><?php echo  trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/");?></title>
```

Comment: <title><?php echo  trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/");?></title> this seems to do part of what i need. this shows /category/music. how could i remove the forward slashes and the word category. Thanks

Comment: <?php echo trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/");?> this is working fine na? what it is returning for u?

Comment: i cant seem to get the trim function to trim out the word category andf still the forward slashes